# PHP htmlspecialchars関数の利用場面を教えて下さい。

Tags: php

PHPの参考書でXSS対策として、「動的に生成される全ての値に対して」エスケープ処理をすべき、との説明があります。
インターネット上では、print　/　echo　の関数と共に簡易に紹介され記事ばかりのような気がします。

実際にサイトの開発作業を進めていく上で、どう活用すべきか理解したいので教えてください。

①html出力時だけで良い
②逆に、画面から入ってくる内容についても（DB書き込む以前に）対応すべき
③上記①の出力項目にしても、当該サイトから登録されたDB上の内容でなければ不要である
（画面制御用のラジオボタンのリストなどは予めDBに登録されているもの、と思う）

一体どれが当てはまるでしょうか？
「動的に生成される全ての値に対して」をもう少し具体的に知りたいです．．．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「動的に」と言うのは、PHPの変数に入っている値は全部、それらからPHPの関数などで作られる値も全部入っている、と考えるといいでしょう。(以下簡単に「変数等」と書きます。)

ただし大前提として、『その「変数等」はHTMLを表していない』場合に限ります。あとで具体例を示します。

「生成される」の部分は「HTMLとして生成される」のことですね。これは字句通り「HTML出力時」ではなく、「HTML生成時」と解釈してください。

***①html出力時だけで良い***

上に書いたように「HTML出力時」でなく、全ての「HTML生成時」に行ってください。

ちょっとした擬似コードで説明します。まずはまったくXSS対策がなっていない方から。

```
<?php
    //...
    $username = ...(DBか入力パラメータかは知らないがユーザの表示名が入る);
    $heading_html = '<h1>'.$name.'さんのページ</h1>';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=$heading_html?>
    <div class="greetings">
      ようこそ、<?=$name?>さん
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

上で(大文字の)「HTML出力時」と言っているのは、`<?=$heading_html?>`や`<?=$name?>`のところですが、このうち`<?=$heading_html?>`にはHTMLのタグなんかが含まれていますから、これを再度`htmlspecialchars`でエスケープしてしまうと、ユーザにタグをそのまんま見せてしまいます。こちらは「HTML生成時」には当たらないと思ってください。

代わりにこちら

```
$heading_html = '<h1>'.$name.'さんのページ</h1>';
```

`$heading_html`は、タグを含む文字列、つまりHTMLなので、この行は「HTML生成時」に含めないといけません。

と言うわけで、上記のコードに正しく`htmlspecialchars`を適用すると、こうなります。

```
<?php
    $name = ...;
    $heading_html = '<h1>'.htmlspecialchars($name).'さんのページ</h1>';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=$heading_html?>
    <div class="greetings">
      ようこそ、<?=htmlspecialchars($name)?>さん
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

基本的には、HTMLとして出力される変数等は必ず、`htmlspecialchars(` `)`で囲む。
HTMLを表す文字列を作成する場合も、変数等は必ず、`htmlspecialchars(` `)`で囲む。
HTMLを表す文字列を出力する場合のみ、例外的に`htmlspecialchars`は付けない。
(その場合は変数名の命名ルールなんかを工夫して「エスケープ不要」であることをわかりやすくした方が良いですね。)

最近はPHPでもテンプレートエンジンなるものを使う例も増えてきているので、その場合、それぞれのエンジンごとに注意点や正しくエスケープする作法なんかが異なります。

***②逆に、画面から入ってくる内容についても（DB書き込む以前に）対応すべき***

これは逆にやってはいけない、にあたります。DBにデータを入れるときにエスケープしてしまうと、HTML生成時に二重エスケープされることになり、ユーザに変な記号を見せることになってしまいます。

※DBに入れるデータにはHTMLのタグ入れちゃいけない、と決めてしまった方が良いでしょう。CMSなんかを自前で作ろうと思うとそうも言ってられないんですが、その場合でも「HTMLが入れられるカラム」と「プレーンテキストのカラム」は明確に分離した方が良いと思います。上の話は「プレーンテキストのカラム」前提です。

※一部のブラウザでは、`textarea`等から送信されてくる文字列に文字実体参照(あるいは数値文字参照、`&...:`とか`&#...;`てやつ)が含まれる場合があります。これではプレーンテキストとして扱えないので、DBの「プレーンテキストのカラム」に格納する際に、ちょっとした前処理が必要になります。(DB,PHPが共にUTF-8に設定していないと、ちょっと大変かも。)

***③上記①の出力項目にしても、当該サイトから登録されたDB上の内容でなければ不要である

（画面制御用のラジオボタンのリストなどは予めDBに登録されているもの、と思う）***

上に書いたようにDBにどのような形式で保存されているかによります。DBにHTMLを登録できるようにしてあるのであれば、それをHTML出力するときにエスケープすると二重エスケープになってしまいます。できるだけそんなDB設計にしない方が良いとは思いますが、避けられない場合にはDBの「HTMLが入れられるカラム」に入れる値を作る時が「HTML生成時」に当たると思ってください。

---

長くなった割には質問者さんが疑問に思われているケースがうまく説明できていないかもしれません。何かありましたら、コメント等でお知らせください。

Comment: ご丁寧なご説明をありがとうございました。
またHTML出力時と当方が記載したばかりに、余計に手を煩わせてしまったようで非常に申し訳ありませんでした。
HTML生成時という解釈をしている前提で、再度確認させて頂ければ幸いです。

画面から入力される内容を、再度画面に表すことさえなければ
この関数の必要性はない？？という解釈をしているのですがそれは間違いでしょうか？

DBに画面デザインを構成する要素（ラジオボタンの羅列やリストボックスの内容）が登録されていて
それらから画面を構成する設計であれば、これらについても当該関数を用いることが妥当、というような記事を目にしたことがあります。

当方は、それら要素に関わるユーザからの送信結果（GET・POST）が、当該サイトから登録される再利用されるデータでなく
予め正規に登録された・限られた選択肢からの内容が戻ってくるだけなので、利用不要と考えています。

ユーザから送信されてくる内容が、画面から入力されるデータ・それらから再利用されるデータ・予め別の場面でDBに登録されていたデータと
と区別がつきにくいので、全ての出力内容に関数を通しておけば無難！という考え方なのでしょうか

一応ちゃんと理解しておきたく．．．．

Comment: 全部の文脈を完全に読み取れていないかも知れませんが…。「ユーザからの送信結果（GET・POST）」については、一切の妥当性を仮定してはいけません。HTMLベタ書きにしろ、DBに検証を受けて登録されているにしろ、ラジオボタンやselectタグで選択した結果なんだから、特定の値しか現れない、などと期待してはいけません。実際攻撃者はブラウザの動作を模するツールを使って攻撃してくるわけですが、ラジオボタンの応答やselectでの選択結果を表すフィールドに不正なコードを仕込んでくることは日常茶飯事です。従って、「無難」だからではなく「現実の脅威から守るために」HTMLを生成する際には、必ずエスケープ処理をしないといけません。(もちろん入口でサニタイジングをしてしまう、と言うのも有効です。サニタイジングと併用するならエスケープ処理は「防御を多重化することで少しでも耐性を高めること」、まぁ、表現の仕方によっては「無難」と言えるでしょう。)ちなみに用語については、「この回答内で」区別の必要が生じたから、書き分けているだけなので、あまりお気になさらずに。

Comment: >ラジオボタンの応答やselectでの選択結果を表すフィールドに不正なコードを仕込んでくることは日常茶飯事です。この認識がなかったです。ご教示を頂きありがとうございます。

これから開発作業に踏み切りたいと思いますので、ご見解を反映していきたいと思います。